# Ms access not updating through VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

```
    pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + "D:\FINAL PROJECT VB INVENTORY MANAGEMENT\Inventory.accdb;"
    connstring = pro
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
    myconnection.Open()

    command = "Update stock set ProductName='" & ProductNameTextBox.Text & "', Quantity='" & QuantityTextBox.Text & "' , Price='" & PriceTextBox.Text & " where ProductID=" & ProductIDTextBox.Text & ""
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)

    MessageBox.Show("Data Updated!")
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myconnection.Close()
        ProductIDTextBox.Clear()
        ProductNameTextBox.Clear()
        QuantityTextBox.Clear()
        PriceTextBox.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't leave the catch section empty. You should deal with whatever exception is being thrown by your code.

Answer (score 0):

You create the command but you never execute it . You need to open the connection and call ExecuteNonQuery on the command.

Comment: tried doing it, still no update to my ms access

Comment: what does this mean? An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is installed on local machine.
And try to run your application in different target platform.
[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement appears to have a problem.

It appears that you have an apostrophe in front of

```
Price='" & PriceTextBox.Text & "
```

but you do not have one after. If this field is numeric, you should not have any apostrophes at all (around the value). This would be the same for the quantity field. Also, it would be better to use a **parameterized** query here, but that does not answer the immediate question. If you fix your SQL syntax and the connection is fine, then the record should update.